# Why isn't Chrome Webdriver saving files when printing with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I'm using a python script and selenium to open various webpages that have a window.print() on them to print a series of pages using kiosk printing. Everything was working as recently as 15-May-2023 when I was on chrome 113, but on 114 with the latest webdriver the dialog opens and it doesn't actually save the file in the specified location.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
import time
import os
import glob
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
s = Service(PATH)

self._experimental_options = {}


def add_experimental_option(self, name, value):
    """
    Adds an experimental option which is passed to chrome.

    Args:
      name: The experimental option name.
      value: The option value.
    """
    self._experimental_options[name] = value


print_settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": "",
    }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(print_settings),
         "download.prompt_for_download": False,
         "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1,
         "download.default_directory": "/Users/seth/Downloads/pdfs",
         "savefile.default_directory": "/Users/seth/Downloads/pdfs",
         "download.directory_upgrade": True,
         "safebrowsing.enabled": True}

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

then I simply load my self-printing page

`driver.get("https://www.heresmyprintingpage.com/1.htm")`

The print dialog loads up like it's printing, but it doesn't print to my specified directory, or anywhere that I can tell. I can't for the life of me figure out why this stopped working with the latest version when I've been using this successfully for more than a year.

I've tried changing the default directory strings, verified that the folder is very permissive.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `Service` ia not defined.   `self` is not defined (it usually suggests the use of a class).  `Options` is not defined, `webdriver` is not defined....  presumably these are from imported modules....  please show if so.